# How to reconnect signalR properly after disconnected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

In my  angular6 website  with ASP.NET server application , 
I want the singnalR client should always stay connected with Hub(Server). For that purpose started the connection on disconnected event with below code snap.

```
    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
        console.log('Now connected');
        this.connectionId = this.connection.id;
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
        this.connectionExists = true;
    }).fail((error: any) => {
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(false);
    });

    this.connection.reconnecting(() => {
        this.tryingToReconnect = true;
    });

    this.connection.reconnected(() => {
        this.tryingToReconnect = false;
    });
    this.connection.error((error: any) => {
        this.initialize();
    });
    this.connection.disconnected(() => {
        if (this.tryingToReconnect) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.initialize();
            }, 5000);

        }
    });;
```

Because of that above code, signalr creates the problem such as
**crashes the client browser and memory leaks** in below cases such as,

1. If there is problem in client internet connection for some hours , that time singalr continuously tries to create the connection with hub. Because of internet problem , **logging the connection error in browser console infinitely** until the successful connection with hub
2. If i close the server, that time  also singalR **logging the connection error in browser console infinitely** until the successful connection with hub

   [image: SignalRErroronConsole]

How to rectify the problems for signalr  always stay connected with Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an incremental value and each reconnect time out would be increased and showing a retry now option, same way Gmail does, is a good practice and would solve both problems.